# React type error "not assignable to parameter of type 'never'"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

What I want to do is loop over current posttype and 'products' but I'm struggling with the types. So I got the following error:

> Argument of type 'Record<string, any>[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.

On this part:

```
...pages.map((page) => ({
```

of my code:

```
  const pages = useSelect((select) => {
    const editor = select("core/editor");
    const currentPostType: string = editor.getCurrentPostType();
    const selectablePostTypes = [currentPostType, "products"];

    const postList = [];

    selectablePostTypes.forEach((singlePostType) => {
      const records: Record<string, any>[] = select("core").getEntityRecords(
        "postType",
        singlePostType
      );

      postList.push(records);
    });
  });

  // Make dropdown of pagesOptions
  const pagesOptions = [
    ...[
      {
        value: "0",
        label: __("No page selected", "demosite"),
      },
    ],
    ...pages.map((page) => ({
      value: page.id,
      label: page.title,
    })),
  ];
```

Add the code which works:

```
  const pages = useSelect((select) => {
    const editor = select("core/editor");
    const postType: string = editor.getCurrentPostType();
    const records: Record<string, any>[] = select("core").getEntityRecords(
      "postType",
      postType
    );

    return records
      ? records.map((record) => ({
          description: record.description,
          id: record.id,
          featuredMedia: record.featuredMedia,
          link: record.link,
          subtitle: record.subtitle,
          title: record.title.rendered,
        }))
      : [];
  });
```

Here it is targeted on one post type, the post-type you're currently editing, but I want to loop this over some posttypes.

Examples:

```
const selectablePostTypes = ['page', 'post', 'product'];
```

Comment: Side note: In there you effectively have this code: `const pagesOptions = [...[somevalue]]` which could just be written as `const pagesOptions = [somevalue]`

Comment: Assuming that `useSelect` is an effect, `const pages = useSelect` doesn't look right. More importantly, the function you pass to `useSelect` doesn't return anything.

Comment: Could you please provide minimum reproducible example in TS playground?

Answer (score 2):

It is your initialization of `postList`

```js
const postList = [];
```

Because you haven't provided it any values for typescript to "figure out" the type signature of the content that should belong in that array, it sets it as

```js
never[]
```

This means it bans you from adding any values to that empty array. Add a type here

```js
const postList: Record<string, any>[][] = [];
```

Comment: If you are seeing this in a simple array then you can type it like this. Before: `var data = {"items": []}`  After: `var data = {"items": <any>[]}`